# Pop-up keyboard in Windows CE 5.0

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce

Is it possible force the build in keyboard to appear within a Windows CE 5.0 application?

I am designing a project in C# and would like the keyboard or a numerical keypad to pop-up when the user has to input to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the `InputPanel` control. Just drop one onto your form from the toolbox. Then just show and hide it on the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events of the input controls:

```
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    inputPanel1.Enabled = true;
}

private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    inputPanel1.Enabled = false;
}
```