# Examples of creating a custom Soft Input Panel for Windows-CE 6.0

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce

Is anyone aware of any example projects that demonstrate creating a custom Soft Input Panel that can be installed on Windows CE 6.0?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to show the soft input panel keyboard as discussed in this question:

[Pop-up keyboard in Windows CE 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156960/pop-up-keyboard-in-windows-ce-5-0)

But then to create a keyboard that matches the look and feel of my application.

Is it even possible to do in windows CE? Or only windows mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, a very good, simple example of a custom SIP is in Doug Boling's book "[Programming Windows CE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735618844)".  See Chapter 18.

One caveat - this has to be written in C (I notice you have the C# tag on the question).

Comment: Thanks ctacke, that was just what I needed. I even found a coworker with copy of the book (with source-code CD) in his office!

Comment: ctacke, are you certain that it isn't possible to create a .Net implementation in C# using COM Interop with the 2.0 compact framework? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm 100% positive.  The SIP must exporse a COM interface, which requires EE Hosting, which doesn't exist in the CF.